# Some posts belonging to sub-categories are not showing in this if statement

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I managed to get this code to work semi-properly (it's filtering posts correctly) however it's only showing 2 of 4 available posts for the category I'm testing ("England").

Live site: https://medievalbritain.com/category/type/medieval-castles/

Category page for England, where other castles I'm missing are shown: https://medievalbritain.com/category/locations/england/

Am I doing something wrong with my `if`? Is there a ***limit*** to how many posts are shown in a page? Could this be a ***theme limitation***, and is there a way to overwrite it?

This is my code:

```
<h3 class="archive-post-title">Castles from England</h3>

<!-- start content container for England -->
<div class="row">

    <?php
        // The Loop 
      if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
        if (in_category('England')):
    ?>

    <div class="archive-post-box col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-4">
          <div>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          </div>
          <h2>
              <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
              </a>
          </h2>
          <p class="archive-post-excerpt">
              <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
          </p>
    </div>

    <?php
          endif;
        endwhile;
      endif;
    ?>

</div>
<!-- end content container for England-->
```

Note I: I'm not a developer.

Note II: I'm using the theme Futurio with Elementor. Above the code I created is this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php futurio_generate_header( true, true, true, false, false ); ?>

    <div class="container-fluid category-custom-header">
        <header class="container text-left">
         <h1>Medieval Castles</h1>
     <?php
     // Display optional category description
        if ( category_description() ) : ?>
       <div class="archive-meta"><?php echo category_description(); ?></div>
     <?php endif; ?>
        </header><!-- .archive-page-header -->
    </div>


<?php futurio_breadcrumbs(); ?>

<?php futurio_content_layout(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wordpress codex entry on [in_category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/) describes the category parameter as a:

> (int|string|array) (Required) Category ID, name or slug, or array of said.

You did not provide a category structure and/or how the post categories are set up so I just gonna assume the category itself is set on any Post. (It would be clearer as to why this happens if you provided those)

The in_category function can also receive a post parameter which should be the current Post ID (which can be retrieved via the [get_the_ID()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) function inside a Wordpress Loop).

Once the in_category function has the post parameter it will ensure your checking against the post and nothing else.

```php
    <?php
      // The Loop 
      if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
        if (in_category('England', get_the_ID())):
    ?>
```

If you are not certain on the Category name you could also provide the ID of the category.

Edit: You could also query the database via WP_Query and only grab the ones within the category instead of filtering them afterwards:

```php
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => 'England',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$posts = new WP_Query($args);

if ($posts->have_posts()) :
    while ($posts->have_posts()) :
        $posts->the_post();?>
        <div class="archive-post-box col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-4">
          <div>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          </div>
          <h2>
              <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
              </a>
          </h2>
          <p class="archive-post-excerpt">
              <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
          </p>
    </div>
    <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried changing it to this, I still only get 2 results (same as before). The structure is: Type (Castle/Town) on one side, and Location (Scotland/England/Wales/Northern Ireland) on the other. Posts belong to one of each. In this case, I want to display only castles from England.

Comment: @Yisela I added a edit on my answer which takes advantage of the QP_Query. That way you could query for the posts in the given category instead of filtering trough them.